# bash count occurrence of multiple words individually in a textfile

Tags: bash, grep, word-count

Basically I need to do this:

```
LOGFILE=error.log

echo $LOGFILE
echo -e "\tERRORs: $(grep -e "ERROR" -c $LOGFILE)"
echo -e "\tDEBUGs: $(grep -e "DEBUG" -c $LOGFILE)"
echo -e "\tFATALs: $(grep -e "FATAL" -c $LOGFILE)"
```

result:

```
error.log
    ERRORs: 3
    DEBUGs: 12
    FATALs: 0
```

But can this be done more efficiently?

Comment: The edit you suggested to hek2mgl's answer was rejected; as you were clarifying your problem, it would have worked much better as en edit to the *question*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `awk`. The following script processes the file in a single run:

```
# count.awk

/Error/{e++}
/DEBUG/{d++}
/FATAL/{f++}

END {
   printf "Errors: %s\n", e
   printf "Debug: %s\n", d
   printf "Fatal: %s\n", f
}
```

Run it like:

```
awk -f count.awk input.file
```

Comment: precise speaking, this is counting the **lines** containing those words, not  **occurrence** of those words. However, for a Log file, those log level key words *usually* has single occurrence per line.

Comment: @Kent Yes, that's the same what the code in the question does.

Comment: I think OP was confused by word occurrence and number of matched lines as well.

Comment: Maybe the OP is indeed confused about that.

Comment: OP wasn't aware that it would make a difference.

Comment: @Asgair It does. What do you want?

Comment: @hek2mgl I tried to explain it editing my original post with some aditional code, but it wasn't allowed by the reviewer. "it would have worked better as an edit to the question." I thought that was exactly what I did. So now I'm confused.

Comment: @hek2mgl To your question: The solution you provided works perfectly. In this case it doesn't matter if I count the lines in which the word occurs, or the the matching word itself. The way I want to apply this is to loop through thousands of new log-files each day OR over several days on request, to generate a XML-report for further processing. I was looking the "fastest" solutions when it comes to processing-time. grep -c is fast, unless you have to execute it for every keyword you want to count. awk is in this case almost as fast, with the benefit it requires only 1 execution for each file.

Comment: `awk` should be as fast as grep with the benefit of looping through the file just once. If you want to loop through 1000's of files, I would first put that folder on a filesystem that supports snapshots, let's say btrfs. Then create a snapshot and use `find ... -exec awk -f count.awk {} \;` on that snapshot (to keep the atomicity). That  should be good enough for most use cases. If not, meaning the log volume is too high, you need to use something more elaborated like elasticsearch, logstash etc..

Comment: @hek2mgl Thanks for the insight! I wasn't aware of btrfs. Sounds interesting. For now I guess awk is the better solution. I was hoping there was a technique with grep I wasn't aware of to achieve the same result. :-)

Comment: I agree that in this case it would be nice if `grep -c -f patterns.txt file.log` could return the count for each individual pattern, but no, that's not how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Using @hek2mgl's answer, I came to this solution:

```
basedir="/path/to/logs"
basedirs_arr=(
/dir1/logs
/dir2/logs
/dir3/logs
/etc/logs
)
summary(){
    for i in "${!basedirs_arr[@]}"
    do
        if [ -d "${basedir}${basedirs_arr[$i]}" ]; then
            find ${basedir}${basedirs_arr[$i]} -type f -iname "*.log" | xargs -I{} sh -c "echo test2 {} ;awk '
BEGIN{
e=0;
d=0;
f=0;
}
/ERROR/{e++}
/DEBUG/{d++}
/FATAL/{f++}
END {
   printf \"\tErrors: %s\n\", e
   printf \"\tDebug: %s\n\", d
   printf \"\tFatal: %s\n\", f
}' {}"
#        else
            # If directory doesn't exist.
            # echo -e "\e[31mdirectory doesn't exist: ${basedir}${basedirs_arr[$i]}\e[0m"
        fi
    done
}
```